# Anbox installation problem

Tags: xubuntu, 17.10, anbox

Whenever I try to install Anbox on my Xubuntu 17.10 machine, I get the following error:

```
error: cannot install "anbox-installer": Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp:
   lookup api.snapcraft.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:39062->[::1]:53: read: connection
   refused
```

For a visual representation:
https://asciinema.org/a/Pisk1bKivlX9ihvE9Pn64cbhC

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be network connection issue.
And please note that Ubuntu 17.10 will EOL soon, consider to upgrade it to 18.04 LTS.

On my 18.04 LTS system I get the following:

```
mate@bionic:~$ snap install  --classic anbox-installer
anbox-installer 1 from 'morphis' installed
mate@bionic:~$ anbox-installer 
The anbox-installer is deprecated. Please find updated installation
instructions here https://github.com/anbox/anbox/blob/master/docs/install.md

For any further questions please ask on the #anbox IRC channel on the
FreeNode network or in the Anbox telegram group (https://t.me/anbox).
```

Visiting https://github.com/anbox/anbox/blob/master/docs/install.md gives us new installation instruction:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:morphis/anbox-support
sudo apt update
sudo apt install anbox-modules-dkms

sudo modprobe ashmem_linux
sudo modprobe binder_linux

snap install --devmode --beta anbox
```

Then consult [official documentation about software installation](https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install_apps.html) or simply run `anbox.appmgr`.

Comment: I got further in the installation process. Now my problem is

`sudo apt install anbox-modules-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package anbox-modules-dkms`

Comment: This means that this PPA [does not have packages for 17.10](https://launchpad.net/~morphis/+archive/ubuntu/anbox-support). You should upgrade to 18.04 LTS as soon as possible.