# error install and run Anbox in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, snap, anbox

I am a newbie to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I want to install Anbox. I am having trouble installing Anbox the way given in the current tutorials. my trouble is

```
$ sudo snap install --devmode --beta anbox
error: snap "anbox" is not available on beta for this architecture (i386)
but exists on other architectures (amd64).
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1054149/66509 .

Answer (score 0):

the answer is simple, you are using a 32-bit(i386) OS. Unfortunately Anbox don't support a 32-bit system(i386).It only exists on 64-bit(amd64).Try installing android on a Virtual Box

Comment: There isn't a 32-bit ISO file for Ubuntu 18.04. New installations of Ubuntu 18.04 are 64-bit only. Maybe a 64-bit OS is installed, but the required anbox-modules-dkms package is not installed. After the anbox-modules-dkms package is installed you have to manually load the kernel modules.

Comment: i'm using 16.04 the same problem is also shown for me too!

Comment: The difference is that 16.04 has both a 32-bit ISO file and a 64-bit ISO file, but 18.04 (like in the question) has 64-bit only.

Comment: Then why does the installation show a message like this

Comment: I'm running 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04LTS, and did not need iso - simply upgraded from 16.10 over the years. Roger on the anbox leaving 32-bit hanging out to dry... and installing android 9 via Virtual Box is a nightmare... 
SEE: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209049/echo-show-8-needs-alexa-app